# To prints the element that is in the fourth row and second column of matrix

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main( ){

    int matrix[][4] = {{14, 10, 6, 4}, {3, 7, 18, 11}, {13, 9, 5, 17}, {19, 12, 2, 1}};
    int sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) 
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 1; j++)
        {
      int num = matrix[i + 3][j + 1];
       printf("%i\n", num);
        }
    }
}
```

// 4th row and 2nd column

But told to access by doing so , i am unable to do so `array[rowNumber - 1][columnNumber - 1]`. Please help

Comment: It doesn't make sense to print a single number in a (nested) loop. Just print item number `matrix[3][1]`, no loops needed.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Not sure what's your issue about and what is your goal.  Providing the error code is recommended.

Answer (score 0):

The description is a little bit ambiguous. Here is a demo showing access elements and iterative elements operations.
BTW, for the `c` language, the indexes are all 0-based. For example index 3 means the 4th element.

```
int main( ){
    int matrix[][4] = {{14, 10, 6, 4}, {3, 7, 18, 11}, {13, 9, 5, 17}, {19, 12, 2, 1}};
    int sum = 0;
    printf("%d\n",matrix[3][1]); // access 4th row and 2nd column
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            sum += matrix[i][j];  // iterative all elements
        }
    }
    printf("sum: %d\n",sum);
    return 0;
}
```